# How can I create a SUM function which only counts the values if a certain column contains a specific value?

Tags: google-sheets

I am playing around with a sheet for time-availability. I was wondering if it is possible to create a `SUM` only for values where another column contains a specific value.

The following is an example of that sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10HyG7-DY_FDxu18EtCP5Na3wLBxmcoQtiFcnESZbZ1k/edit?usp=sharing

Here's a screen shot, with the solution (posted below).

[image: Screenshot of the sheet (with solution)]

- Column A contains the person's name.
- Column B contains the project name.
- The individual cells contain the amount of time (hours) that person has planned for that project on that day.

On the bottom I added an overall total. And some empty total rows per project. That's where I was at a loss. So, considering row #18 (Total for "Proj 1"), how can I tell Google Sheets to: "Calculate the SUM of of the above cells, but *only* consider cells where `B<n> == B18`".

Maybe I can play around with a Pivot Table on a separate sheet, but having it immediately visible in the first sheet would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's annoying... 1h searching for a solution and 5min after posting it here on SO, I found it ... -_-

For posterity:

The function to use in this case is `SUMIF`. It needs to be used with 3 arguments:

- The first contains the project name: `$B$4:$B$16`
- The second contains the criterion. In this case we can use `$B18`
- The third contains the cells which contain the values: `C$4:C$16`

The full function reads: `=SUMIF($B$4:$B$16, $B18, C$4:C$16)`

Note that some values are "pinned" and must be fixed when new rows are added to the sheet!

I also added the formulas to the example sheet linked above  for reference.